# Setting width for video tag

Tags: html, iframe

I have a code

```
<iframe id="vdoiframe" src="http://keralacarpentry.com/immobiler/media_gallery/BMP2_PSP.mp4" height="500" width="950">
</iframe>
```

my question is how can we set a width to audio tag using css?.In this code my video is small.i want to increse its width.Is that possible to set width to this audio tag ?.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than link to the video in an iframe can you link using the <video> tag? That way you can control the size, placement, auto-play, controls etc using the HTML5 capabilities

```
<video height="250" width="320">
    <source="http://keralacarpentry.com/immobiler/media_gallery/BMP2_PSP.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```